# Apple Server & Windows 10 & CalDav

Tags: windows, apple

I'm running Apple Server 5 on a Mac Mini. The Mac's connect fine locally and remotely via L2TP VPN using SMB. We have a couple of Windows machines, which again are okay connecting locally to the Server. However, out of the office is another story. I've only been able to connect with PPTP VPN to the server and that's as far as I can get. I cannot connect to the server file sharing. No matter what I input as the address I'm unable to connect. Any help would be great???

Also, does anyone know of an easy way for windows Outlook (or some sort of calendar app on Windows) to connect to the Apple servers Calendar (CalDav).

Comment: You should open a new question for your second question.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check mentioned below:-

(1) Permission for user to use VPN in Active Directory Domain Service.

(2) Configure TCP/IP with relevant IP address on client.

( 3) Map FQDN of the VPN server to the client's etc file and check the network connectivity between client and VPN Server by using ping command.  The client must connect if it is pinging.

(4) If L2TP (Layer-2 Tunneling Protocol) is configured with pre-shared, then make sure you are using right key.

(5) If L2TP has Certificate, then download it from CA (Certification Authority) and install on client.

(6) Issue with a specific user or all.

(7) Check VPN firewall for Inbound and Outbound requests.